# Difficulty adding a "3 Player Mode" in PyGame Using A Button Function

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, pygame

One of the requirements for my PyGame is to include a "3 Player Mode", and  to distinguish the mode using buttons. I want the "play" button to be 2 players only (default number of players), and the "3P" button to add an extra player to make it 3 players (ignore the CPU button). I have implemented some code in an attempt to make it work. At the moment, whenever I click on the 3P button, it only shows 2 players. Is there anything I need to add or take away? I also have a game loop, but I made no changes there in regards to this problem.

This is where I identified my players:

```
shipImg = pygame.image.load('ship1.png')
shipImg = pygame.transform.scale(shipImg, (73,73))

shipImg2 = pygame.image.load('ship2.png')
shipImg2 = pygame.transform.scale(shipImg2, (73,73))

shipImg3 = pygame.image.load('ship3.png')  
shipImg3 = pygame.transform.scale(shipImg3, (73,73))
useimage3 = False #3rd player is initially set to false
```

This is my button function. As you can see one of the items listed within the parameters is "player3". As stated within the conditional statement in the function, later on in the game introduction function (where the buttons are located), I will set that value to "True" in order to make player 3 visible.

```
def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac, player3,action=None):
mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac, (x,y,w,h))
    if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
        action()

if player3 == True:
    useimage3 = True

else:
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,ic, (x,y,w,h))

smallText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',20)
textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg,smallText, white)
textRect = ((x+(w/2-25)), (y+(h/2+-10)))
gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)
```

In my introduction function, I set all of my players variables to either "True" or "False". My first two players (p1 and p2) are set to True (as that's the default number of players for my game), and player 3 is set to "False, as I only want it to be added if the "3P" button is clicked. As a result, I implemented the button function and put "True" within the parameters for "player3" in the "3P" button and "False" for the rest of the buttons.

```
def game_intro():

intro = True

while intro:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    gameDisplay.blit(background,(0,0))
    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',75)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects('WARPED!',font, white)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height-500))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',40)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects('Use the arrow keys to avoid the aliens!',font, white)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    shipImg = True
    shipImg2 = True
    shipImg3 = False    


    button("PLAY",50,450,100,50,green,bright_green,False,game_loop)
    button("QUIT",650,450,100,50,red,bright_red,False,quitgame)
    button("CPU",250,450,100,50,blue,bright_blue,False,game_loop)
    button("3P",450,450,100,50,purple,bright_purple, True, game_loop)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(15)
```

Comment: text `'WARPED!'` and `'Use...'` never change so you could generate them only once - before `while`.

Comment: `useimage3` inside `button` is local variable and doesn't change global variable `useimage3` which you have outside this function. You have to add `global useimage3` inside `button()` to inform function that you what to use external/global variable instead of creating local one when you use `=` .

Comment: BTW: you can simple do `useimage3 = player3` without `if`. And you have to do before you execute `action()` and only if you clicked button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`userImage3` iside `button()` is local variable and it doesn't change global variable which you have outside functions. You have to inform function that it has to use this global variable and doesn't create local one when you use `=`

```
def button(msg, x, y, w, h, ic, ac, player3=False, action=None):
    # inform function to use external/global variable 
    # and not create local one when you use `=`
    global useimage3

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    button_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)

    if button_rect.colidepoint(mouse):
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac, button_rect)
        if click[0] and action:
            # now we doesn't create local variable but we change global one
            useimage3 = player3
            action()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic, button_rect)

    # you could do it only once before `while` loop
    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',20)

    # you could do it only once before `while` loop 
    text_image, text_rect = text_objects(msg, font, white)

    # you could do it only once before `while` loop 
    # center text on button
    text_rect.center = butto_rect.center

    gameDisplay.blit(text_image, text_rect)
```

BTW: I saw this `button()` function many times before and I have to say that it awful - it create font, text, image, etc. again and again (wasting only time and CPU) but it could create this element before `while` loop and keep on list or dictionary like

```
def generate_button(msg, button_rect):

     font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',20)
     text_image, text_rect = text_objects(msg, font, white)
     text_rect.center = button_rect.center

     return text_image, text_rect

# --- 

button_play = ["PLAY", pygame.Rect(50, 450, 100, 50), green, bright_green, False, game_loop]

text_image, text_rect = generate_button(button_play[0], button_play[1])

button_play + = [text_image, text_rect]

# ... other buttons ...

while intro:

     button(button_play)
     button(button_quit)
     button(button_cpu)
     button(button_3p)
```

and

```
def button(button_data):
    # inform function to use external/global variable 
    # and not create local one when you use `=`
    global useimage3

    msg, button_rect, ic, ac, player3, action, text_image, text_rect = button_data

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if button_rect.colidepoint(mouse):
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac, button_rect)
        if click[0] and action:
            # now we doesn't create local variable but we change global one
            useimage3 = player3
            action()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic, button_rect)

    gameDisplay.blit(text_image, text_rect)
```